# Find lowest latest and average milk production?

Tags: python

i have set of line which i read from file in to list . Each row is a new record and each row consist 3 numbers and 1 letter. There are 5 condition in it

```
507 W 1000 1
1 M 6 2 
1 W 1400 3
1 M 8 8
1 T 101 10
507 M 4 12
1 W 1700 15
1 M 7 16
507 M 8 20
```

1) The first element is a cow ID a unique number representing a cow inside the data set.

2) The second element is a action code 'W' 'M' 'T'.

3) if 'W' is come then the 3rd element is the latest weight of cow.

4) if 'M' is come then the 3rd element is the amount of milk the cow produce.

5) if 'T' is come then the 3rd element is the current temperature of cow.

6) IMPORTANT: if a cow doesn't have least one W and least M then exclude it from the output.

output: (id , lowest weight , max weight , average milk)

```
507 1000 1000 6
1 1400 1700 7
```

My output is correct but how should i apply the 6th condition in my code?

my code

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

arr = []
with open(filename, "r") as fileToProcess:
    for line in fileToProcess:
        arr.append(line.strip().split(' '))
#print(L)

if not arr:
    print("EMPTY")

else:
    lst2 = [item[0] for item in arr]
    # print(lst2)
    mylist = list(set(lst2))
    # print(mylist[0])

    sum_1_M = 0
    sum_1_W = 0
    list_1 = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(mylist)):
        for x in arr:
            if x[0] == mylist[i] and x[1] == 'M':
                sum_1_M += int(x[2])
                count = count + 1
            elif x[0] == mylist[i] and x[1] == 'W':
                sum_1_W += int(x[2])
                list_1.append(int(x[2]))
                list_1.sort()
        print('{} {} {} {}'.format(mylist[i], list_1[0], list_1[len(list_1) - 1], int(sum_1_M / count)))
        sum_1_M = 0
        sum_1_W = 0
        list_1 = []
        count = 0
```

Comment: ***" how should i apply the 6th condition"***: Count the `M/W` by `Cow ID` using any container data type.

Comment: Note that an ideal question factors out everything unrelated to the specific issue you're asking about, removing specifications and code unless the issue can't be addressed without them (so code should still be complete enough to run, but any parts of it that you don't have a problem with should be taken out, allowing data to be likewise simplified).

Comment: As it is, this question and its answer are unlikely to help anyone else, unless they're solving the same assignment posed around cows and milk. A better question would focus around the software engineering problem, not the assignment it was encountered in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can actually calculate everything while reading, the key is to use a dictionary and updates entry while parsing line by line. Take a look at this code I made for you,

```
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

dic = {}
with open(filename, "r") as fileToProcess:
  for line in fileToProcess:
    arr = line.strip().split(' ')
    if arr[0] not in dic:
      dic[arr[0]] = {
        'min_weight': 99999999,
        'max_weight': 0,
        'total_milk': 0,
        'count_milk': 0
      }
    if arr[1] == 'W': 
      if dic[arr[0]]['min_weight'] >= int(arr[2]):
        dic[arr[0]]['min_weight'] = int(arr[2])
      if dic[arr[0]]['max_weight'] <= int(arr[2]):
        dic[arr[0]]['max_weight'] = int(arr[2])
    elif arr[1] == 'M':
      dic[arr[0]]['total_milk'] += int(arr[2])
      dic[arr[0]]['count_milk'] += 1

for k, v in dic.items():
  if v['max_weight'] > 0 and v['total_milk'] > 0:
    print('({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(
      k,
      v['min_weight'],
      v['max_weight'],
      v['total_milk']/v['count_milk']
    ))
```

Comment: is your satisfy the 6th condition?

Comment: it is checked when iterating the dictionary, this condition is the 6th `v['max_weight'] > 0 and v['total_milk'] > 0`. If `max_weight` is not the initial value `0` and `total_milk` is not the initial value `0` then it prints (of course I am assuming that no cow has zero weight and no cow gives zero milk)